# Generating combinations using sql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following records in a MySQL sample database.

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║ Title        ║ Value       ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ A<sub>1</sub>║ 1           ║
║ 2 ║ A<sub>2</sub>║ 10          ║
║ 3 ║ A<sub>3</sub>║ 3           ║
║ 4 ║ B<sub>1</sub>║ 5           ║
║ 5 ║ B<sub>2</sub>║ 7           ║
║ 6 ║ C<sub>1</sub>║ 8           ║
║ 7 ║ C<sub>2</sub>║ 23          ║
║ 8 ║ D<sub>1</sub>║ 3           ║
║ 9 ║ Z<sub>1</sub>║ 0           ║
║ 10║ Z<sub>2</sub>║ 11          ║
║ 11║ Z<sub>3</sub>║ 22          ║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Generally the records will be these many:
A<sub>1</sub>, A<sub>2</sub>, ... , A<sub>n</sub>, B<sub>1</sub>, B<sub>2</sub>, ... , B<sub>m</sub>, ....... , Z<sub>1</sub>, Z<sub>2</sub>, ... , Z<sub>p</sub>

Given a user input, for example `(A,B,Z)`, I want to generate all possible combinations from the database of the form

> (A<sub>i</sub>, B<sub>j</sub>, Z<sub>k</sub>)

where

> 1<=i<=n, 1<=j<=m, 1<=k<=p

So for input (B,D) I should get

```
╔═══╦══════════════╦═════════════╗
║   ║              ║             ║
╠═══╬══════════════╬═════════════╣
║ 1 ║ B<sub>1</sub>║D<sub>1</sub>║
║ 2 ║ B<sub>2</sub>║D<sub>1</sub>║
╚═══╩══════════════╩═════════════╝
```

I have accomplished this in java but I have no clue how to go about doing this using MySQL.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: MySQL is not PLSQL, which is Oracle.  Please post your data as an actual table.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Sorry my bad. Edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is a `CROSS JOIN`, which generates every possible combination of rows in the tables being joined.  So if you did

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 
  CROSS JOIN table t2
  CROSS JOIN table t3;
```

You would get literally all possible triplets of variables.  You could then add `WHERE` conditions for the relevant triplets:

```
SELECT * FROM table t1 
  CROSS JOIN table t2
  CROSS JOIN table t3
WHERE t1.Title LIKE 'A%'
  AND t2.Title LIKE 'B%'    
  AND t3.title LIKE 'C%';
```

This would give you all (A,B,C) triplets.

If your tables are large, your cross joins will be impractically large, so it's usually better to cross join subqueries:

```
SELECT * FROM
  (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Title LIKE 'A%') t1
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Title LIKE 'B%') t2
  CROSS JOIN (SELECT * FROM table WHERE Title LIKE 'C%') t3;
```

This will prune down the relevant rows before multiplying them out.  This is almost always more efficient.

https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/advance-query-in-mysql/mysql-cross-join.php